# What does "main screen" actually refer to, in battery usage?

Tags: iphone, battery, ios

On iOS 8, there is the battery usage screen showing an estimate of the battery use, per application.

It also has an entry for "Main screen". I assumed it was just displaying the main screen with the icons, but I got 40% of that during night, during which the screen was indeed off.

As such, what does "Main screen" refer to, exactly?

Comment: Did you receive notifications during night? Maybe this is why. Perhaps you could try do not disturb mode during nights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/#ios:

> **Home & Lock Screen.** This indicates that the Home screen or Lock screen
>   was displayed on your device. For example, the display was awakened by
>   pressing the Home button or by a notification.
>
> - If an app frequently wakes your display with notifications, you can turn off push notifications for the app in Settings > Notifications.
>     Tap App and set Allow Notifications to Off.